# Sub-domain DNS records not transferring from BIND to W2k8 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, bind

We're in the process of migrating from Bluecat Adonis (BIND) DNS appliances to Windows 2008 R2 DNS servers.

I configured company.com to transfer from the BIND appliance, and all of the records in it appear to transfer successfully.  However, there are several sub-domains which transfer, but the records within them do not.  For example, albuquerque.company.com transfers, but does not contain any records.

If I configure one of the sub-domains as a top-level forward lookup zone, the records transfer successfully.

The ACLs on the BIND appliance appears to be correct.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A zone transfer will only copy records in the zone that's being queried.  The appliance seems to have a separate zone configured in BIND for the subdomains; those records will not be included in a transfer request for the parent domain.

In order to populate the Windows servers via zone transfers, you'd need to mirror the zone configuration exactly; if the BIND server has a zone defined for the subdomain, the Windows server will need to have its own secondary zone configured to transfer it.

Comment: Thanks Shane.  You're right; each subdomain has its own zone file.  That's why it wasn't transferring.  I'll either import the records for each subdomain, or configure secondaries for each subdomain explicitly.